# Issue with building paypal here sdk

Tags: android, paypal

I'm trying to allow customers to pay with their credit card on my app. So I followed [these instructions](https://goo.gl/OxefWe) to run the paypal here sdk sample app but I'm having trouble building the sample app. It gives me the following errors.

:processDebugResources
warning: string 'sdk_dlg_title_card_swipe' has no default translation.
C:\Users\HaMiD\Downloads\Source\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\21.0.2\res\values-sw600dp\values.xml
Error:(2) Resource entry abc_action_bar_default_height_material is already defined.
C:\Users\HaMiD\Downloads\Source\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\paypal-here-sdk\res\values-sw600dp-v13\values.xml
Error:(2, 1) Originally defined here.

Next, I added the SDK to my own project (File->New->New Module->aar) and add compile project(':PayPalHereSDK') to the build.gradle. But when I try to build the project I get the exact same error once again. For some reason I'm having issues building with the SDK. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that was an issue with SDk 1.6. The new version (1.6.1) that posted to github a few hours ago doesn't have this problem anymore.

Thanks guys